# Display flex not working on Material UI's box item

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, localhost, github-pages

I've created a *create-react-app* project, where I'm using Material UI. Here I've used *Box*  item with `display="flex";` inline style. But the flex is not working at all. Here is an image.

[image]

When I add add `display: flex` on the inspect element. It works.

I've uploaded the project to github pages. Funny thing is, it works fine on there. Here is the link of the [uploaded page](https://drougnov.github.io/travel_guide/). Why is it not working as intended in the local host server?

```js
<AppBar position="static">
            <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
                <Typography variant="h5" className={classes.title}>
                    Travel Advisor
                </Typography>
                <Box display="flex">
                    <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                        Explore new places
                    </Typography>
                    <div className={classes.search}>
                        <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
                            <SearchIcon />
                        </div>
                        <InputBase placeholder="Search..." classes={{ root: classes.inputRoot, input: classes.inputInput }} />
                    </div>
                </Box>
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
```

Comment: May be adding this attribute could resolve your issue : <Box sx={{display: "flex"}}/>

Comment: @Alik64 thanks for the reply but it didn't work.

Comment: OP is using MUI v4, which is why `sx` is not working for him.